# In azure devops, Can I Create a Backlog where items don't show in the kanban board

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

I am setting up a process in azure devops based off the agile process
When I create a story (or feature etc) in the "backlog" section, it shows up on my kanban board.  I want to keep my stories that aren't ready to begin being worked on somewhere else so i dont have a huge list of stories on my board.

Any idea about how to do this?

For clarification...I've added an item to the backlog but not yet assigned it to a sprint:
[image]

And here is the kanban board.
[image]

Since I haven't assigned the story to an iteration yet, i don't want it to show on the board...
Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've not set up any iterations yet. By default, you'll have 1 iteration. Go to `https://yoururl/_settings/work` and create some child iterations.

[image]

Anything which is on the backlog would have the base iteration path, with items in an active/future sprint/iteration having a child iteration path set.

Comment: I updated the initial post to show more what i am trying to do.  Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @shuri17 can you show me your iterations from the `_settings/work` page, and the iteration path set on your work item, please? You can update your question.